Finding MLE given dependent observations from uniform distribution $U(0,\theta)$
Suppose we are given random variables $X_1,...,X_n$ that are uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,\theta]$, with $\theta >0$ unknown.  I know that if the $X_1,...,X_n$ are furthermore independent, we can conclude that the Maximum Likelihood Estimation is given as $\hat{\theta} = \max\limits_i x_i$.
I was wondering if the same conclusion also holds if the random variables $X_1,...,X_n$ are not independent. My main problem is that I am unable to determine the Likelihood function, which I do not know if it is possible if the $X_i$ are not independent.
I would appreciate any help.

It’s the multivariate density

Intuitively, it doesn't seem to me like the samples being dependent would change the MLE ? The maximizer of the likelihood should still be the max of the $x_i$ because anything less than the max of the $x_i$ is not possible. The likelihood only exists for $\hat\theta$ = the maximum of the $x_i$ or greater.

@markleeds I understand that intuitively, we should obtain the same MLE, however, I was not able to prove it. I also understand that it should be zero is the $x_i$ are less than $0$ or greater then $\theta$. I was not able to show that the function is then decreasing for $\theta > \max\limits_i x_i$

There is no way to determine the likelihood function when you don't know the dependence structure of the $X_i$'s.

@user007: Based on the answer's below, it looks my comment is totally wrong. My apologies. I would delete my comment but then your comment and stubbornatom's comment would not make sense.

The hypothesis that the sample maximum is the MLE, even if there are dependencies, is false. The MLE really depends on how the $X_i$ depend on each other. Consider this example:
$$
X_1 \sim U(0, \theta)
$$
$$
X_n \sim U(0, \theta/2)\,\, \textit{if}\,\, x_1<\theta/2
$$
$$
X_n \sim U(\theta/2, \theta)\,\, \textit{if}\,\, x_1>\theta/2
$$
for $n>1$. You can see that, marginally, each $X_i$ is $U(0, \theta)$, but they are not independent.
Now suppose that you observe $x_1 = 0.1$ and $\max {x_i} = 0.9$. The likelihood of $\theta$ being 0.9 is zero, since, being $x_1<0.9/2$, every subsequent $x_i$ should have lied in the $[0, 0.45]$ interval. The MLE here is 1.8, twice the maximum observed value.

nicola: neat example. I didn't realize that dependence meant that the  marginal distribution can be different for each $X_i$.

Yes, I considered the marginally uniform a requirement for each $X_i$. The MLE depends on the joint probability function.

@nicola Apologies, not sure what I was thinking. This works, +1

@nicola thank you for the simple and easy to understand answer

By definition, when $X_1,\dots, X_n$ are dependent, the MLE is $X_{(n)}=\max\limits_i X_i$ if

A: and $X_1,\dots, X_n$ have a joint pdf $f$


B: The parameter $\theta$ only affects the univariate marginal distributions of the joint distribution of $(X_1,\dots, X_n)$.


C: The joint pdf of $\left ( \frac{X_1}{\theta},\dots, \frac{X_n}{\theta} \right )$ is increasing in each of its arguments.

Condition A is considered so that the analysis of the likelihood function becomes easier in the following (the ML method can be used for a more general case where the density is defined as the Radon-Nikodym derivative of the probability distribution relative to a dominating measure other than Lebesgue measure). Condition B is used to make sure that the distribution of $\left ( \frac{X_1}{\theta},\dots, \frac{X_n}{\theta} \right )$ is independent of $\theta$.
Under these conditions, for $0\le x_i \le \theta, i=1,\dots,n$, we have
$$f \left ( x_1,\dots, x_n \right )=\left ( \frac{1}{\theta} \right )^n g \left ( \frac{x_1}{\theta},\dots, \frac{x_n}{\theta} \right ) $$
where $g: [0,1]^n\to \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ is the joint pdf of $\left ( \frac{X_1}{\theta},\dots, \frac{X_n}{\theta} \right ).$ Then, we have
$$l(\theta)=\left ( \frac{1}{\theta} \right )^n g \left ( \frac{x_1}{\theta},\dots, \frac{x_n}{\theta} \right ) I(\theta \ge x_{(n)})$$
where $g$ is independent of $\theta$ under condition B. Hence, under C, the MLE of $\theta$ is $X_{(n)}$.

Condition B is equivalent to that the copula $C$ associated with $X_1,\dots, X_n$ is independent of $\theta$, that is, in the following Sklar's representation:
$$F_{X_1,\dots, X_n} \left ( x_1,\dots, x_n \right )=C\left ( F_{X_1}(x_1),\dots, F_{X_n}(x_n) \right ),$$
the copula $C$ is independent of $\theta$. In this case, condition A is equivalent to that the copula $C$ has a joint pdf $g$, and condition C means that $g$ is increasing in each argument.
Note that in the independence case,  for $u\in [0,1]^n$, we have $$C(u_1,\dots, u_n)=u_1×\cdots×u_n,$$ with $g(u_1,\dots, u_n)=1,$ and all the three conditions A, B, and C are satisfied.

Counterexample in lack of C:
For $n=2$, consider observations $x_1=x_2=5$ where the joint copula of $\frac{X_1}{\theta}, \frac{X_2}{\theta}$ is assumed to be the Frank copula [1] with parameter $-2$. Then, as you can see below from the plot of $l(\theta)$ [2], the maximum likelihood estimate of $\theta$ is a number greater than $x_{(2)}=5$.


I am not sure A is required to use the maximum likelihood method:  if $X_1 \sim U[0, \theta]$ and $X_i=X_1$ for all $i$ then there is still a likelihood $\big($proportional to $\frac1\theta, \mathbf I_{[0\le X_1\le \theta]}\big)$, but no joint density.

@Henry Thanks for your comment! To use ML method, we need the density of data, which can be a joint pdf (in A, I used this case), a joint pmf, or more generally the Radon-Nikodym derivative of the probability distribution relative to a dominating measure. For the example you gave, we may use the general case.

@Amir thank you for the detailed answer. The reason I accepted nicola's answer is, that the counterexample is simpler

@user007 You are welcome! I appreciate your kind consideration! I like Nicola's answer too. Actually, it could be guessed that the claim couldn't not hold generally, so I was not seeking to only present a counterexample. My answer provides sufficient conditions under which the claim holds. Hope weaker conditions will be presented.
